# KIVY: Changing line colour in Paint App

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

How can I change line color in the kivy Paint app that I have made. I am able to change width of line, but I couldn't find anything for changing color of line.

My code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line
class DrawRandom(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"]=Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y),width=5)
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DrawRandom()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply add Color to your canvas.
In your imports import Color too.

```
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
```

And in your Painter class add Color to canvas. In this example I try red.
Its rgba values.

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(1,0,0,1)
        touch.ud["line"] = Line( points = (touch.x, touch.y))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I missed importing Color. That was making life miserable.

Comment: @thechargedneutron you are wellcome :)